# A program that converts 16 bit positive number in binary

Tags: c

i am trying to write a program such that if a % 2^j = 0 then it prints 1 , else it prints 0 so at the end i get a 16 bit binary code. But i get no error and after i enter an input number (a) terminal crashes.
Thank you for your help.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  uint16_t a, j, b, mod;
  printf(" Please insert a number between 0 and 65535 \n ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  j = 16;
  while (j > 0)
    ;
  {
    b = pow(j, 2);
    mod = a % b;
    if (mod == 0) {
      printf("%d", 1);
    } else {
      printf("%d", 0);
    }
    j = j - 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d", &a);` --> `scanf("%hu", &a);`

Comment: Note that [`pow`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/pow) is a floating point function. And that `pow(anything, 2)` is supposed to be exactly equal to `something * something`. I suggest you use multiplication instead. But beware of overflows, and be ready to handle them.

Comment: I suspect you meant `pow(2, j);` rather than `pow(j, 2);`. However, on the first iteration, `j` will be 16, and `pow(2, j);` is 65536.0 will be converted to 0 when assigned to `b` (since `b` is only 16 bits wide). That will result in a divide-by-zero error on the following line: `mod = a % b;`. Besides, the math in the loop is all wrong anyway, You should be using `j` values from 15 down to 0, and checking if the corresponding bit is set in `a`, not checking if `a % b` is zero (assuming the intention is to print the value in base 2).

Comment: Any time you write `pow(2,x)` you make an old programmer cry. That's basically using 100+ instructions for what should be 1, and maybe getting the wrong answer. Try `(1 << x)`.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker  Perhaps `(1u << x)` to shed one less tear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you use the `%d` format for [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). This format specifier expects the argument to be a pointer to `int`.

Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to UB.

For `uint16_t` use the macro `SCNu16` (as documented in e.g. [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer#Format_macro_constants)):

```
scanf("%" SCNu16, &a);
```

Comment: Also the `;` after `while` is definitely an error. My formatting should make it easier to spot.